# IntelliJ Gradle Could not Determine Java Version

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gradle

I'm using IntelliJ to work with a Gradle project. I noticed that whenever I try to refresh the Gradle project (or when trying to import/re-import a project as a Gradle project) I get the following error:

`Error: Could not determine the Java version`

`$JAVA_HOME` is set, the SDK is set to Java 8 (and gradle -version confirms it is also is set to Java 8), and the project builds fine from the command line. Restarting IntelliJ also does nothing. I also deleted the project specific and global `.gradle` folders, which did not resolve the issue.

I am running IntelliJ 14.1.4 on Ubuntu 15.04 and Gradle 2.5.

EDIT: Tried it on a different machine (also Ubuntu 15.04, Oracle Java 8) running IntelliJ 14.1.1 and it worked correctly.

Comment: Are you sure that IntelliJ has an SDK set for the project?

Comment: Yes, and it is set to Java 8.

Comment: Which JRE Intellij itself runs on?

Comment: Java 8. All are running on Oracle's version. I also tried OpenJDK's version.

Comment: Try cleaning the caches: https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/cleaning-system-cache.html

Comment: Still doesn't work. Also see my comment above about how it works fine in IntelliJ 14.1.1 on a machine of identical specifications.

Answer (score 5):

I had this problem too. It seems it was linked to the project being setup with a rather old gradle build. Changing distributionUrl to a new distribution in /gradle//wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties solved it

Comment: services.gradle.org/ distributions/

Comment: Worked, thanks. If "gradle" directory in your project is missing, you need to install Gradle wrapper: 1) Install Gradle in your OS 2) From command line run `gradle wrapper` on your project 3) Update the version in gradle-wrapper.properties

Answer (score 1):

You should try to switch Idea boot jdk. It works for me.